# Java server sending byte array over TCP socket to Android clients

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, bitmap

I have a server device and N client devices. I want to send pictures to each client from the server.
My problem is the client doesn't receive the whole image. I converted the Bitmaps to byte array before I send it.

Send Bitmaps on the Server:

```
try {
  OutputStream out = clients.get(i).getSocket().getOutputStream();
  //Convert Bitmap to byte array:
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
  byte[] byteImage = stream.toByteArray();
  //Send the byte array
  if(byteImage.length > 0){
   out.write(byteImage, 0, byteImage.length);
   out.flush();
  }
  out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}`
```

Receive image on the Client:

```
try {
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] data = new byte[1024];
  int length = 0;
  while ((length = in.read(data)) != -1) { //in --> InputStream
    out.write(data, 0, length);
    out.flush();
  }
  byte[] bytePicture = out.toByteArray();
  out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Before I send the image, I tell the size of the byte array of the Bitmap to the clients.

My problem is the **received bytes < send bytes**. Why?

On the server side I created threads for all clients to send the images them.

EDIT:

I use PrintWriters to communicate with messages between the server and the clients.
I send the length of the byte array from the server to the clients before I start to send the byte array.

```
PrintWriter writer;
writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)), true);
writer.println("BYTE#" + byteImage.length);
writer.flush();
```

When a client get a message, which starts with "BYTE#" on the client side, I start to read the byte array:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
final String message = reader.readLine();
if (message != null && message.startsWith("BYTE#")){
  //Get the length of the byte array (correct)
  int length = Integer.valueOf(message.split("#")[1]);
  //... Start to read the byte array here...
}
```

Comment: 1. You're ignoring all exceptions on the reading side. 2. You haven't shown the code where you send or receive the length. 3. You're closing the `ByteArrayOutputStream` *after* getting its byte array. Fortunately its `close()` method does nothing, but if it did it should come *before* `toByteArray().`

Comment: @EJP I didn't copy my whole code here, because I thougth some part is totally unnecessary to show. I modified my question to give more information about my code.